# Question on Algebraic Proof of Inclusion Exclusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

There are many proofs of the Principle Inclusion-Exclusion, including some nice ones involving from theory of posets and generating functions.

I recently heard it claimed that you can prove Inclusion-Exclusion by interpreting the expansion of
$$(1-X_1) (1-X_2) \dots (1-X_n) $$
suitably in some algebra over posets, where the product $XY$ is taken to be the meet of two elements $X\wedge Y.$

Could anyone fill in the details for this claim? Or, provide a reference that might have some information about what sort of algebra the above claim is referring to?

Comment: This might be related to: [Ottavio d'Antona and Gian-Carlo Rota, *Two rings connected with the inclusion-exclusion principle*, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A, Volume 24, Issue 3, May 1978, Pages 395--402](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(78)90069-9). Although these two rings are not really like the one you're describing.

Comment: Related: [O. d'Antona and A. Pesci, *Connecting two rings underlying the inclusion-exclusion principle*, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A, Volume 40, Issue 2, November 1985, Pages 439--443](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(85)90104-9).

Comment: Actually, it's easier than that. Let's say that you have a finite family $\left(A_i\right)_{i \in I}$ of subsets of a finite set $E$, and you want to prove that $\left| E \setminus \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i \right| = \sum\limits_{J \subseteq I} \left(-1\right)^{\left|J\right|} \left| \bigcap\limits_{i \in J} A_i \right|$. (This is one form of the principle of inclusion and exclusion.) First of all, notice that each subset $S$ of $E$ satisfies $\left|S\right| = \sum\limits_{e \in E} \left[e \in S\right]$, where ...

Comment: ... the notation $\left[\mathcal{A}\right]$ stands for the truth value of a statement $\mathcal{A}$ (this truth value is defined to be $1$ if $\mathcal{A}$ is true, and $0$ otherwise). This allows you to rewrite the cardinalities in the equality as sums over all $e \in E$. Thus, it remains to check that $\left[ e \in E \setminus \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i \right] = \sum\limits_{J \subseteq I} \left(-1\right)^{\left|J\right|} \left[ e \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in J} A_i \right]$ for each $e \in E$. But the left hand side of this equality can be rewritten ...

Comment: ... as $\left[ e \notin \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i \right] = \left[ e \notin A_i \text{ for all } i \in I \right] = \prod\limits_{i \in I} \left[ e \notin A_i \right] = \prod\limits_{i \in I} \left(1 - \left[ e \in A_i \right]\right)$, whereas the truth value $\left[ e \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in J} A_i \right]$ on the right hand side can be rewritten as $\left[ e \in A_i \text{ for all } i \in J \right] = \prod\limits_{i \in J} \left[ e \in A_i \right]$. Thus, the equality in question becomes a particular case of the ...

Comment: ... well-known equality $\prod\limits_{i \in I} \left(1 - a_i\right) = \sum\limits_{J \subseteq I} \left(-1\right)^{\left|J\right|} \prod\limits_{i \in J} a_i$, which holds for any finite family $\left(a_i\right)_{i \in I}$ of elements of a commutative ring. This may well be a version of the proof you are looking for, although it does not per-se use any abstract algebra (the commutative ring we are working in is $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Oh that's very cool, I haven't seen that approach before, thanks! I'm assuming that's not the approach that was originally suggested to me, but it certainly does work.